# Calling mv creates uneeded extra subdirectory

Tags: bash, mv

Given two distincts dirs `/foo` and `/bar`,

where ls /foo will return
myFile.pdf
and ls /bar will return empty

I want to move `foo` in `bar` so I eventually get `/foo/bar`. 
So I type

```
mv /bar /foo
```

It does work but it creates an extra level such as

/foo/bar/bar/myFile.pdf

I can't see any reasons why it behaves like this. Any ideas ?

Comment: Please add the output of `ls /bar` and `ls /foo` to your question.

Comment: Which `shell` variant are you in ?

Comment: I don't see how `/foo/bar/bar/contents` could result from this command unless `/bar/bar/contents` already exists.

Comment: tried to add ls comments but can't save the edits :\

Comment: @Inian, on a Mac OS 10.10.5 terminal

Answer (score 0):

Really? You have /bar and /foo in root dir?

If you start with

```
/foo/file.pdf
/bar/
```

And do 'mv /bar /foo'

You will get:

```
/foo/file.pdf
/foo/bar/
```

Something in your description of initial conditions or in command run is incorrect?

'mv /bar /foo/' is more explicit.